# Which static analysis tool can detect VS C4552 (operator has no effect) issue

Tags: static-analysis, cppcheck

During development bug was introduced, the semicolon ; added in between expression.
This is [compiler warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C4552)&rd=true), but [cpp check](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) 1.78 not reported anything.

```
        const auto winTotalCredit = m_outcomeStorage.getWinCredits() * m_outcomeStorage.getWinMultiplier();
        + m_outcomeStorage.getBonusCredits();
```

is there any static analysis tool which will warn about this?

Comment: It is not clear why question marked as off topic. One who have mark this as off topic maybe can help and hint what need to be fixed.

Comment: @Daniel Marjamäki  any suggestion why cpp check is not detecting this?

Comment: nice idea..I created a ticket: http://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/8004

Comment: @DanielMarjamäki thanks for response, is the ticket public so we can track and see when it is done.